# How to take a function that checks if a pair of elements added together equal another integer and make it run in linear time?

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, time-complexity

So I have to write a function in Python that takes a sorted list and an integer and checks if the total of any pair of elements in the list equal the integer. It also has to run in linear time(Or O(n) time). I have the function to do the task complete but it runs in quadratic time. Here is my function:

```
def sum_to_int(l, k):
    Lst=sorted(l)
    for i in range(len(Lst)):
            for n in Lst[i:]:
                    print(Lst[i]+n==k)

def main():
    l=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    k=10
    sum_to_int(l, k)

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

I'm pretty sure that in order to make this run in linear time I have to remove the second for loop but I'm not sure of how I can go through the list without the second loop. Is there anyway I can simplify this function & make it run in linear time? Any help at all would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this pretty easily with a set:

```
def sum_to_int(sum_value, sorted_ints):
    s = set(sorted_ints)
    return any((sum_value - v) in s for v in s)
```

there might be issues in using a number twice, e.g, `sum_to_int(4, [2])` would return `True`, but you could fix this by using a `Counter` from `collections`

Answer (score 2):

My code probably isn't exactly pythonic, since I'm not too proficient with python. If anyone can provide some neat code doing the same, feel free to edit :). Anyways, the basic idea is the following:
For any pair of values out of the list, if their sum if smaller than the searched value, we try the next larger value for the smaller one of the pair. If their sum is larger than the searched value, we try the next smaller value for the larger one of the pair. Else we found a match and can either terminate or try with the next pair in the list. This runs in `O(n)`.

```
def find_sum(ls, k):
    l, u = 0, len(ls) - 1
    while l < u:
        sum = ls[l] + ls[u]
        if sum == k:
            print("Found: {} + {} = {}".format(ls[l], ls[u], k))
            l += 1
            u -= 1
        elif sum < k:
            l += 1
        else:
            u -= 1
```

E.g.:

```
l = [1, 3, 4, 9, 10, 23, 56], k = 13

1    3    4    9    10    23    56
1                               56 = 57 => too large, reduce upper value
1                         23       = 24 => too large -=-
1                   10             = 11 => too small, try with larger value
     3              10             = 13 => found a match, try with the next number-pair
          4    9                   = 13 => found another match
```

You can just rely on the fact that it works and ignore the next section, unless you're interested in a proof.

How this works in detail:
Let `l` and `u` be the index of the lower/higher value of the list `ls`. Now let `l` be fixed. Then there (may) exist indices `u1` and `u2`, such that `ls[l] + ls[u1] < k` and `ls[l] + ls[u2] > k`, where `u1` is maximum and `u2` minimum. In the window defined by `u1` and `u2` might be another index, let's call it `u'`, with `u1 < u' < u2`. If `u'` exists, it must hold the value matching `ls[l] + ls[u'] = k`, which we report. Else, `l` gets incremented and we continue by searching `u'` for the new `l`. Obviously `u' <= u1` must hold, as otherwise the order-constraint of our list would be violated. When we reach `l >= u1`, we have reached the point where no new pairs can turn up, as we've exhausted the search-space, and the algorithm terminates.